# Access Denied You don't have permission to access "http://www.pizzahut.com/" on this serve

Tags: internet-connection

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.pizzahut.com/" on this server.
Reference #18.afce5640.1570568492.1fdbd2b9
```

Why do I keep getting this on all of my browsers I use on my desktop computer? And I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Looks like content filtering of some sort?  Can you show a screenshot?  Maybe view the source of the page for clues?  Pastebin link the source if possible?

Comment: Are you connecting from work or school?

Answer (score 1):

It´s probably because of use of VPN. More and more websites block you if you use VPN. I´m not sure why, but they do.

Comment: He didn't say anything about using a VPN.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Had to close fiddler to be able to see pizzahut.